# Cant fully slide to answer call IPhone 4

Tags: iphone, bug, unlock

As the title describes, sometimes, but not too rarely, when I have an incoming call I cannot fully slide the lock to answer. It will get to like 20-30% and then jump at the start. Sometimes after many tries ill make it while other times i just lose the call. There seem to be lots of people with this issue but couldnt find an answer.

Problem happens on IPhone 4 with latest software running. This occurs with calls coming from contacts but 99% of incoming calls are from contacts anyway.

Comment: This happens on my 3GS sometimes. I think it's just a software issue that we don't have any control over. You could always DFU restore the phone if you wanted to make 100% sure your OS is ok.

Comment: I've had this. Whether they're a contact or not is irrelivent. I suspect (with absolutely no evidence) it's related to sweaty or dirty fingers leaving a receptive streak across the slide area. Rather than the phone seeing a fingertip move across the screen, it sees a finger grow across the screen much larger than a figertip should be.  I quickly plugged in the hands-free and answered it with that.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food the thing you mention cannot have anything to do with it although thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: @hellothere so you havent found a solution?

Comment: Not for sure, I normally just clean my screen with isopropyl wipes and restart the phone

Comment: I just did a reset. In couple of days I will know if it worked.

Comment: @latusaki - hand-e-food is correct, actually. Here in Florida, the humidity is quite high and if there is any condensation or sweat on your fingers, it causes touch inaccuracies. Wiping the screen and your finger fixes the problem immediately. Everyone down here experiences this daily, it's never been a software or hardware problem in my experience. It's worse on earlier iPhones because the oleophobic coating isn't as effective.

Comment: I've had this problem with both a 3GS and a 4S.  I don't think it's related to greasy fingers because turning the screen off, then on always fixes the problem immediately.  That's not a great option when you're trying to answer the phone, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a month after doing the reset, the issue has not appeared, so I believe this has been solved. Dirt on the screen did not apply on my case but I guess it can cause this issue in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem many times. To solve it I had to reset my iPhone 3G settings. To do so just go to **Settings / Reset / Reset All Settings**. You will not lose any of your data.